# Don't fire the app in the foreground on tap on notification in android

Tags: android, notifications

I've successfully implemented the push notification in android. here is two ways i'm using this

1. App closed: tap on notification opens the app and do the work
   needed.
2. App in foreground : notification comes and do the work needed.

Right now, The requirement is **I don't wanted to open the app when user tap on the notification when app is closed**.

But needed the 2nd functionality (when app in foreground).

I don't think it is possible, But need some experts views on this :) is it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tries I got that it is possible, you have to just pass the empty intent. thats it.